'feast.ui_server' is not a package
I am trying to test Feast UI according to the tutorial https://docs.feast.dev/reference/alpha-web-ui
My actions
pip install feast==0.38.0
feast init test_ui # created a project
cd test_ui/feature_repo
feast apply -- OK
feast serve -p 8008 # started feast server 127.0.0.1:8008 -- OK

#in the same folder
feast ui --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8009 # I was trying different ports 8008 etc -- ERROR

Error details:

feast ui --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8889
/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/feast/ui_server.py:45: DeprecationWarning: 
        on_event is deprecated, use lifespan event handlers instead.

        Read more about it in the
        [FastAPI docs for Lifespan Events](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/).
        
  @app.on_event("shutdown")
/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py:4495: DeprecationWarning: 
        on_event is deprecated, use lifespan event handlers instead.

        Read more about it in the
        [FastAPI docs for Lifespan Events](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/).
        
  return self.router.on_event(event_type)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/bin/feast", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
             ^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1157, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1078, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1688, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1434, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/core.py", line 783, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 33, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/feast/cli.py", line 172, in ui
    store.serve_ui(
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/feast/feature_store.py", line 2494, in serve_ui
    ui_server.start_server(
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/feast/ui_server.py", line 105, in start_server
    app = get_app(
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/aamoskalenko/0_root_folder/02_dev/35_feast_ui/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/feast/ui_server.py", line 54, in get_app
    ui_dir_ref = importlib_resources.files(__name__) / "ui/build/"
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/resources/_common.py", line 22, in files
    return from_package(get_package(package))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/resources/_common.py", line 55, in get_package
    raise TypeError(f'{package!r} is not a package')
TypeError: 'feast.ui_server' is not a package

